# Anding with 0xff, clarification needed

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

In the following snippet consider replacing line 8 with commented equivalent

```
1. private static String ipToText(byte[] ip) {
2.  StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
3.
4.  for (int i = 0; i < ip.length; i++) {
5.      if (i > 0)
6.          result.append(".");
7.
8.      result.append(ip[i]); // compare with result.append(0xff & ip[i]);
9.  }
10.
11.     return result.toString();
12. }
```

`.equals()` test confirms that adding `0xff` does not change anything. Is there a reason for this mask to be applied?

Comment: I'm not sure, but looks like converting to unsigned byte.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`byte` in Java is a number between −128 and 127 (signed, like every integer in Java (except for `char` if you want to count it)). By anding with `0xff` you're forcing it to be a positive `int` between 0 and 255.

It works because Java will perform a widening conversion to `int`, using sign extension, so instead of a negative `byte` you will have a negative `int`. Masking with `0xff` will leave only the lower 8 bits, thus making the number positive again (and what you initially intended).

You probably didn't notice the difference because you tested with a `byte[]` with only values smaller than 128.

Small example:

```
public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] ip = new int[] {192, 168, 101, 23};
        byte[] ipb = new byte[4];
        for (int i =0; i < 4; i++) {
            ipb[i] = (byte)ip[i];
        }

        for (int i =0; i < 4; i++) {
            System.out.println("Byte: " + ipb[i] + ", And: " + (0xff & ipb[i]));
        }
    }
}
```

This prints

```
Byte: -64, And: 192
Byte: -88, And: 168
Byte: 101, And: 101
Byte: 23, And: 23
```

showing the difference between what's in the `byte`, what went into the byte when it still was an `int` and what the result of the `&` operation is.

Comment: Re: "This is because `0xff` is of type `int`, therefore the byte gets promoted to `int` as well": The type-promotion to `int` would actually happen even if both arguments had type `byte`; Java doesn't have a distinct `&` operator for `byte`. (And in the version with no `&`, the type-promotion to `int` would happen during overload resolution, since `StringBuffer` doesn't have an `append(byte)` method.)

Comment: Indeed, you are right. The relevant part is obviously that we get a sign-extended widening to `int` in any case and by masking the lower 8 bits we can force it to be an unsigned byte again :)

Comment: "unsigned, like every integer in Java" - Do you mean signed?

Comment: @NabinBhandari: of course, thanks. You could just have edited as well.

Answer (score 3):

As you're already working with an array of bytes here, and you're doing a bitwise operation, you can ignore how Java treats all bytes as signed. After all, you're working on the bit level now, and there is no such thing as "signed" or "unsigned" values on the level of bits.

Masking an 8-bit value (a byte) with all 1's is just a waste of cycles, as nothing will ever be masked off. A bitewise AND will return a bit true if both bits being compared are true, thus if the mask contains all 1's, then you're guaranteed that all bits of the masked value will remain unchanged after the AND operation.

Consider the following examples:

```
Mask off the upper nibble:
    0110 1010
AND 0000 1111 (0x0F)
  = 0000 1010
```

```
Mask off the lower nibble:
    0110 1010
AND 1111 0000 (0xF0)
  = 0110 0000
```

```
Mask off... Eh, nothing:
    0110 1010
AND 1111 1111 (0xFF)
  = 0110 1010
```

Of course, if you were working with a full blown int here, you'd get the result at the others have said: You'd "force" the int to be the equivalent of an unsigned byte.

Answer (score 1):

In this example, I don't see how it would make any difference. You are anding the 0xff with a byte. A byte by definition has 8 bits, and the add masks off the last 8 bits. So you're taking the last 8 of 8, that's not going to do anything.

Anding with 0xff would make sense if the thing you were anding with it was bigger than a byte, a short or an int or whatever.

Comment: Whoops, I confess, I misread the question. I was thinking it was putting it back into an array of bytes, I didn't catch that it was converting it to text.

Answer (score 1):

This should only make a difference if there are negative bytes.  `& 0xff` is typically used to interpret a byte as unsigned.