# What is SHA-256 for? And how to create it in Java?

Tags: java, security, hash, hex, sha

I read SHA-256 from a book, but the book doesn't explain what it is for? The book explained how to create it in Java. However, I failed to understand what `Integer.toString((byteData[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1))` is for. Can someone explain it to me in detail?

[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function#Applications

Comment: SHA-256 is not related to converting a number to hexidecimal.

Comment: SHA 256 is a hash algorithm. But seriously: if you have no idea what that is all about; forget using it. Typically, you need hashing, and cryptography in order to achieve some level of "security". But that is not a topic for beginners. In other words: asking such questions about such topics somehow implies that you better look out for other topics to study.

Comment: so, what topic should I learn then? I learn programming by myself. Thus, I have no idea what the next step I should take.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Integer.toString((byteData[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1))
```

is one way of converting a byte value to a string that's exacly two character wide, showing the byte's hexadecimal value. Having a look at [String's Javadoc page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) will help.

The combination of `0x100` and `substring(1)` ensures that byte values < than 16 decimal (that is, 0 to F in hex) are also represented as two characters.

By the way:

```
String.format("%02x",byteData[i])
```

does exactly the same, and might be considered more readable, especially by people who are used to C printf style format strings.

Lastly, why `(byteData[i] & 0xff)` ? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9949919/112079) for a detailed explanation:

> It works because Java will perform a widening conversion to int, using
>   sign extension, so instead of a negative byte you will have a negative
>   int. Masking with 0xff will leave only the lower 8 bits, thus making
>   the number positive again (and what you initially intended).

Comment: Could you give an example of converting a byte to a hexadecimal?

Comment: That's exactly what both the `Integer.toString` and my `String.format` suggestion do, so I don't understand your question?

Comment: Now I understand how to convert it to hexadecimal, but I have one more question. is & 0xff important? doesn't byte always be equal to 8 bits? So why do we need to make sure it is 8 bits? thanks!

Comment: @LukasHerman forget the previous comment, I expanded my answer with the correct explanation.

Comment: Thanky you. Now that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

SHA-256 is called a hash algorithm, and its purpose is simple: it takes any data and generates a unique series of bytes to represent it.  There is no way to reverse this process, and there are no known instances of a SHA-256 hash being not unique.

The purpose of the line of code in question is to generate one character of the final SHA-256 output.  Java gives you the has in raw data (a byte array) and we typically convert it to hexadecimal to represent it as a string.  That line of code is pretty complex, so I'll go over what each part of it does separately.

`sb.append();` is taking the imput and adding it to the result stored in a StringBuilder.

`Integer.toString();` Takes a number and represents it as a literal string

`byteData[i] & 0xff` Selects the current byte of hash data and uses the bitwise and operation using 0xff (so for each bit in the byte, if the corresponding bit in 0xff is the same, the output is a 1, if not the output is a 0.

`string.substring(1);` Outputs the string starting after the first character.

Comment: Your answer is also good, but you didn't explain what "0x100" is for. I appreciate your help.